# How to convert scala vector to spark ML vector?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections, apache-spark-ml

I have a vector of type `scala.collection.immutable.Vector` and would like to convert it to a vector of type `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector`.

For example, I want something like the following;

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
val scalaVec = Vector(1,2,3)
val sparkVec = Vectors.dense(scalaVec)
```

Note that I could simply type `val sparkVec = Vectors.dense(1,2,3)` but I want to convert existing scala collection Vectors. I want to do this to embed these DenseVectors in a DataFrame to feed into spark.ml pipelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectors.dense can take an array of doubles. Likely what is causing your trouble is that Vectors.dense won't accept Ints which you are using in scalaVec in your example. So the following fails:

```
val test = Seq(1,2,3,4,5).to[scala.Vector].toArray
Vectors.dense(test)

import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
test: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
<console>:67: error: overloaded method value dense with alternatives:
  (values: Array[Double])org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector <and>
  (firstValue: Double,otherValues: Double*)org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector cannot be applied to (Array[Int])
   Vectors.dense(test)
```

While this works:

```
val testDouble = Seq(1,2,3,4,5).map(x=>x.toDouble).to[scala.Vector].toArray
Vectors.dense(testDouble)

testDouble: Array[Double] = Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
res11: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
```

Comment: Thanks @pwb2103! This was indeed the problem. Looking at the source code shows `def dense(values: Array[Double]): Vector = new DenseVector(values)` confirming what you have answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass vector element as var-args as follows :

```
val scalaVec = Vector(1, 2, 3) 
val sparkVec = Vectors.dense(scalaVec:_*)
```

Comment: Thanks @Kuladip, but this doesn't work for me; I'm using scala 2.11 and spark 2.1. I get "no `:_*' annotation allowed here (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)"